# Condition IF in PHP

Tags: php

I have the code :

```
   function insertChamado($id, $area = 2)
   {

   if ($area != 2 && $area != 4)
    $area = 2;
```

How Can I adjust this code to not accept 0 condition as show in the log bellow :

```
[12-May-2016 16:58:28 America/Sao_Paulo] id = 36445, area = 0
[12-May-2016 16:59:00 America/Sao_Paulo] id = 14635, area = 0
[12-May-2016 17:00:02 America/Sao_Paulo] id = 18599, area = 0
```

Comment: To not accept? What would you want it to do? `if($area == 0) { //don't accept }`.

Comment: your conditional statement  will never equal 2 "and" 4, you want "or".

Comment: @Fred  are you sure? what about area = 3 ? :)

Comment: @Fred-ii- But it can be NOT 2 AND NOT 4 ;)

Comment: @splash58 I guess I'm missing something then *lol*

Comment: @JonStirling I'm confused by it *lol* it's just me then.

Comment: Guys, thanks ,  How Can redirect the condition 0 to 2 or 4 ?

Comment: @MilitarBrasileiro That question makes no sense, though I think its partially due to a language barrier. And since 0 meets the original condition of being neither 2 and 4, if you implement this function properly, which I suspect you are not, then you can never have 0.

Comment: You want to allow `0` as well or...? 0 isn't 2 or 4. Maybe you want to check if the value is `0`, `2`, or `4`? If so maybe `if (in_array($area, array(0,2,4)) {`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- what if [2 equals 4?](http://virgil.azwestern.edu/~dag/lol/TwoPlusTwo.html)

Comment: @Drew what if 9 equals cats? *lol*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading carefully your question i think that your best solution is a simple `switch`.

```
function insertChamado($id, $area = 2){
    switch ($area) {
        case 2:
            echo "area equals 2\n";
            break;
        case 4:
            echo "area equals 4\n";
            break;
        default:
            echo "area is always 2 other wise\n";
    }
}

insertChamado('id',0); // will output "area is always 2 other wise"

insertChamado('id'); // will output "area equals 2"
```

Comment: We went through all that and the guy just wanted to know how to use a switch case? He could have just used if/else if for that matter lol....

Answer (score 2):

Just add a conditional to check for it... Not sure what is hard about it unless we are missing something.

```
   function insertChamado($id, $area = 2)
   {
       if ($area == 0) die("Ruh-Rohh");
       if ($area != 2 && $area != 4)
           $area = 2;
   }
```

Or if you expect it to be 2 if it is 0:

```
   function insertChamado($id, $area = 2)
   {
       if (($area != 2 && $area != 4) || $area == 0) // Though || $area == 0 actually does nothing here as 0 already meets the previous condition.
           $area = 2;
   }
```

It occurs to me after the fact, that $area could never be 0 even in your original code as 0 != 2 and 0 != 4 thus $area = 2. I suspect an implementation issue, if this does not help I suggest you edit your ques to include more code.

Could be a scope issue, as you are not using a global $area and are not returning a value, the changed $area may not be breaking out of the function.

Try one of the se implementations:

Using global

```
$area = 0; // for testing only
function insertChamado($id)
{
    global $area;
    if ($area != 2 && $area != 4)
        $area = 2;
}
```

Or using a return:

```
$area = insertChamado(0,0);
function insertChamado($id, $area = 2)
{
    if ($area != 2 && $area != 4)
        $area = 2;
    return $area;
}
```

The incomplete code you supplied does not help as I have no idea what the implementation of `id` is.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Its a silly ques so I had to add some humor just to keep from going insane lol

Comment: Hehe, yeah that Scooby's a hoot!

Comment: adding `|| $area == 0` does not change anything

Comment: @splash58 commented the code line to reinforce this fact.